# bit shift strange behavior when put value in a variable

Tags: c, overflow, compiler-warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int e = 100;
    printf("%x %x \n", 1<<(100), 1<<e);
    printf("%x %x \n", 0xffffff<<(100-23), 0xffffff<<(e-23));

}
```

output

```
main.c:14:25: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
     printf("%x %x \n", 1<<(100), 1<<e);
                         ^~
main.c:15:32: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
     printf("%x %x \n", 0xffffff<<(100-23), 0xffffff<<(e-23));
                                ^~
0 10 
0 ffffe000
```

I don't know why this happens, could anybody explain this to me? I think both should be 0, but what compilers did there ?

Comment: From the C specification of the bitwise shift operators: "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, **the behavior is undefined**". It is not productive to explain the result of UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#:%7E:text=In%20any%20case%2C%20if%20the%20value%20of%20the%20right%20operand%20is%20negative%20or%20is%20greater%20or%20equal%20to%20the%20number%20of%20bits%20in%20the%20promoted%20left%20operand%2C%20the%20behavior%20is%20undefined.) for bit shift operators:

> In any case, if the value of the right operand is negative or is
> greater or equal to the number of bits in the promoted left operand,
> the behavior is undefined.

In your case, your left operand is of type `int`, which is *most probably* 32 bits in size. You are shifting it by much more than that and hence the warnings (and subsequent undefined behavior).

Answer (score -1):

UB. The result is not predictable.

[image]

Comment: This give me a good visualization. thanks!